# How do you check the length of a double in C++

Tags: c++

I'm using this code to check that a student number being entered is the correct number of digits. Is there a function like .length() that will work for the variable type double? Thanks!

```
do {
    cout << "Student's number: (Numeric only)";
    cin >> studentNumber;
    cin.ignore();
}
while (studentNumber.length() != 6);
```

Comment: If it's a student ID, don't use a double -- use a long instead.

Comment: Where is the declaration for `studentNumber` - e.g. what type is it?

Comment: This looks like a canonical homework question, so I suggest that you might be wise to perform more validation than just the length of the number and consider what happens when non-numeric input is encountered.

Comment: The declaration is higher up in the code.

Comment: You're right about it being homework, that isn't actually required for the assignment but how would I check for characters along with the length?

Comment: I'll rephrase that.  Would you care to share it with us?

Comment: It's being passed to the function that code is in by the main. Do you want me to post the two functions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read it as text, validate it, then parse it:

```
std::string input;
bool valid = false;
while (!valid) {
    cout << "Student's number: (Numeric only)";
    cin >> input;
    if (input.size() == 6)
        valid = true;
}
double studentNumber = strtod(input.c_str());
```

Answer (score 7):

Read it as a string, check it's length while it is still in that representation (also check that it consists only of `[0-9]`), then convert to a double. Actually, only convert to a double at all if you are going to do math with it. Otherwise keep it as a string.

In general taking user input in non-string types is fraught with danger. Read it as a string, validate and convert.

Comment: Actually this makes more sense. So if I change the variable to a string from the start how can I ensure characters aren't entered?

Comment: @Blake Use something like [`std::string::find_first_not_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_first_not_of) to validate that the entry consists only of the digits [0,9]

Comment: Consider `std::string::find_first_not_of` or a related method. If your instructor requires you to work with c style strings there is `strsep`. The standard libraries are your friends.

Answer (score 3):

```
do {
  cout << "Student's number: (Numeric only) " << flush;
} while( !( cin >> studentNumber ) || 
         ( studentNumber < 100000 ) || 
         ( studentNumber > 999999 ) );
```

Placing `cin >> studentNumber` within the `while` also ensures that the text entered by the user was successfully converted to what ever type `studentNumber` is.

Comment: I thought about doing it that way but I know there has to be a way to check the length too. Thanks though.

Comment: @Blake You can check length with log10. Same idea.

Comment: @blake a further hint: what happens when the extract operator on an `istream` fails to convert - for instance due to invalid input?  Exceptions? some other failure mode?  What does studentNumber contain

Answer (score 3):

Can't you just use `<` and `>`?

```
// Require that studentNumber be 3 digits
if(studentNumber < 100 || studentNumber >= 1000) {
    cout << "bad" << endl;
}
```

Comment: @CrazyEddie Then you fire whoever came up with the system that generates IDs.

Answer (score 3):

If you switch to an integral type, simple division can accomplish this:

```
long studentNumber;
do {
    // get number
} while (!(studentNumber / 100000L) || studentNumber / 1000000L);
```

If you actually want the number of digits in an integral type:

```
int long_digits(long l)
{
    // this code will work for negative numbers, but we don't want them
    if (l < 0L)
        throw std::out_of_range("no negative numbers please");

    int count;
    for (count = 0; l; l /= 10L, ++count);
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use [log10](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cmath/log10/)? then you need to round downthe result, maybe using [floor(double)](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cmath/floor/) to find the integer

```
//remember math.h
#include <math.h>

do {
    cout << "Student's number: (Numeric only)";
    cin >> studentNumber;
    cin.ignore();
}
while (floor(log10(studentNumber)) != 6);
```

EDIT:
A little explanation: log10 allows you to find x in this equation

```
10^x=y
```

where y is given and is your exponent.

Long story short, `studentNumber` must be of 6 'chars', we can write this as

```
10^5 <= studentNumber < 10^6
```

or

```
5 <= log10(studentNumber) < 6
```

and then

```
floor(log10(studentNumber)) ==5
```

only if it is a number of 6 digits in the integer part.